# How to implement a function which allocates in dynamic way memory for one-dimensional array of integers in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

How can we implement the function `void v_alloc_table_add_5 (int iSize)`, which allocates memory in a dynamic way for a one-dimensional array of `int` variables?

> The size of an array is specified by the `iSize` parameter. The array elements should be initiated on `offset+5`. Limitations are:
>
> - When array is allocated and initialized, display all array elements.
> - Remember that you need to deallocate memory using delete before end of the program.
> - The function should be protected against an invalid `iSize` parameter value.

My Code so far:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void v_alloc_table_add_5(int iSize)
{
    int *myarr = new int[iSize];

    for (int i = 0; i < iSize; i++)
    {
        myarr[i] = 4;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < iSize; i++)
    {
        cout << "Elements are: " << myarr[i] << endl;
    }

    delete[] myarr;
}

int main()
{   
    cout << "Array size?" << endl;
    int input;
    cin >> input;
    const int iSize = input;

    v_alloc_table_add_5(iSize);

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: This seems like homework...

Comment: I Agree. May I ask that homeworks are not allowed here by the way?

Comment: You implemented the function. What is your question?

Comment: Homework is no Problem per se, but even more unlikely than usual you will get a full solution for the homework as answer. Apart from the question that seems to be your task, what is your specific question? What is wrong with the solution you have ?

Comment: Homework is allowed, but it will be handled slightly differently and usually more in hints and suggestions than outright answers. No one wants to have to work alongside someone who cut-n-pasted their way to a job.

Comment: Also if this wasnt homework the answer would be to use a vector

Comment: Keep an eye on point three. I recommend sitting down with a pen and paper and defining for yourself what makes a value of `iSize` invalid. Only after you have the rules worked out can you successfully write code to implement those rules.

Comment: See [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/)